# ValueError: Found array with 1 feature(s) while a minimum of 2 is required

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection

I applied Random Forest RFECV among other ML models to a churn dataset.
While Logistic, SVC, Gradient Boosting, Decision Trees worked well on the data (all using RFECV),
Random Forest RFECV decided that only one feature was important and eliminated all the other features.
Code:

```
#Create Feature variable X and Target variable y
y = churn_dataset['Churn']
X = churn_dataset.drop(['Churn'], axis = 1)

#RFECV
rfecv = RFECV(RandomForestClassifier(), cv=10, scoring='f1')
rfecv = rfecv.fit(X, y)
print('Optimal number of features :', rfecv.n_features_)
print('Best features :', X.columns[rfecv.support_])
print(np.where(rfecv.support_ == False)[0])

#drop columns
X.drop(X.columns[np.where(rfecv.support_ == False)[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
rfecv.estimator_.feature_importances_

#train test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.20, 
                                                    random_state=8)

#fit model
random_forest = rfecv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The following error is returned:

```
ValueError: Found array with 1 feature(s) (shape=(1622, 1)) while a minimum of 2 is required.
```

Output of churn_dataset.head()

```
    name  gender churn last_purchase_in_days order_count  purchase_quantity ...
2   ACKLE   0   1   0.317604    -0.453647   2   -0.368683   1.173058    0.291104    0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1.00
4   ADNAN   1   1   0.250814    -0.453647   2   -0.368683   -0.431351   -0.418023   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1.00
5   ADY     0   1   -1.143415   -0.453647   2   -0.368683   0.190767    -0.117630   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1.00
6   ANDY    0   1   0.768432    -0.453647   2   -0.368683   -0.752232   -0.559952   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1.00
7   AGIE    0   0   -1.669381   3.048875    8   -0.368683   0.520653    4.251851    0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0.16
```

`churn_dataset.columns`

```
Index(['name', 'gender', 'Churn', 'last_purchase_in_days',
       'order_count', 'quantity', 'disc_code',
       'AOV', 'sales',
       'channel_Paid Advertising','channel_Recurring Payment', 
       'channel_Search Engine',
       'channel_Social Media', 'country_Denmark', 'country_France', 
        'country_Germany', 'country_Italy',
       'country_Luxembourg', 'country_Others', 'country_Switzerland',
       'country_United Kingdom', 'city_Düsseldorf', 'city_Frankfurt',
       'city_Hamburg', 'city_Hannover', 'city_Köln', 'city_Leipzig',
       'city_Munich', 'city_Others', 'city_Stuttgart', 'city_Wien',
       'Probability_of_Churn'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Can you add post the output of `churn_dataset.head()`?

Comment: edited. The numeric columns are mostly feature scaled.